# RSQL : How to query for null column values?

Tags: java, spring, parsing

I tried using a custom operator but it does not seem to be working.
is there any way to check null values in RSQL?

```
Set<ComparisonOperator> operators = RSQLOperators.defaultOperators();
operators.add(new ComparisonOperator("=isnull=", true));

Node rootNode = new RSQLParser().parse("name=isnull=null");
```

Link :

```
https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser/blob/master/README.adoc#how-to-add-custom-operators
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the new operator you need to pass the operators instance to `RSQLParser()` so that it can override the default operators:

```
Node rootNode = new RSQLParser(operators).parse("name=isnull=null");
```

Comment: Do you know where put the functionallity for this?? can you show me all the code?